# Html radiobutton: несколько штук

Tags: html

У меня в одной форме 6 радиобутонов. Как их разделить чтобы при выборе можно выбрать 2 радио бутона. Кидать каждые 3 радио бутона в разные формы? Только так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
<form name="myform" action="myformhandler.cgi" method="POST">
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter" checked> Butter<br>
<input type="radio" name="group1" value="Cheese"> Cheese
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Water"> Water<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Beer"> Beer<br>
<input type="radio" name="group2" value="Wine" checked> Wine<br>
</form>
```

Иначе динамически распределить никак не получится, так как кнопка **должна** принадлежать предварительно обозначенной группе. Для произвольной выборки используйте чекбоксы - для этого они и предназначены.

Можно, - в зависимости от постановки задачи, - динамически рисовать элементы формы и присваивать нужную группу нужной радио-кнопке на момент отрисовки, чтобы разделить элементы по заданным группам, в которых выбор будет равняться только одному выбранному элементу, но это слишком нецелесообразно.

Comment: спасибо помогло.

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/U5sTz/

Смысл в том, что у кнопок одной группы должно быть одинаковое имя.